# Local diffeomorphisms, covering maps and smooth path lifting

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, covering-spaces

Let $f: M\to N$ be a surjective local diffeomorphism of noncompact smooth manifolds.
Suppose that every smooth path is liftable, that is, for any smooth path $\gamma: [0,1]\to N$ and any point $p\in f^{-1}\gamma(0)$ there exists $\tilde \gamma: [0,1]\to M$, such that $\tilde \gamma(0)=p$ and $f\circ \tilde \gamma=\gamma$.
By smooth path here I mean a map $[0,1]\to N$ that extends to a smooth map $(0-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)$.

Does it imply that $f$ is a covering?

In our situation being a covering is equivalent to the lifting property for *continuous* or *rectifiable* paths but the proofs that I am aware of ([https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/cov.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekapovich/EPR/cov.pdf)) apparently do not go through when we know how to lift only smooth paths. The bottleneck is lifting homotopies.

Actually I am interested in cases where the class of liftable paths is even more restricted, though still abundant, like the class of *piecewise linear paths*.

In general, even if we can approximate uniformly a given path: $\gamma_i\to \gamma$ as ${i\to\infty}$, with $\gamma_i(0)=\gamma(0)$, $\gamma_i(1)=\gamma(1)$ and $lenght(\gamma_i)\to lenght(\gamma)$ by paths *that lift* to $\tilde\gamma_i$ with $\tilde\gamma_i(0)=p\in f^{-1} \gamma (0)$ and $\gamma$ is liftable on $[0,1)$, it does not allow us to conclude that $\gamma$ is liftable on the whole $[0,1]$. So, even if the answer to the question is 'yes', it likely doesn't follow for free by an approximation argument.

Answer (score 3):

To show that $f$ is a covering map, pick any point $n∈N$.
Choose an open neighborhood $U$ of $n$ that is diffeomorphic to ${\bf R}^n$.
It suffices to show that the restriction $g\colon V\to U$
of the map $f$ to any connected component $V$
of $f^{-1}(U)$ is a diffeomorphism.

The map $g$ is surjective because otherwise the smooth
path lifting property is violated for a smooth path that connects
a point in the image of $g$ with a point not in the image of $g$.

The map $g$ is injective: if $g(x)=g(y)$, choose a smooth path
$p\colon[0,1]→V$ that connects $x$ and $y$.
Choose a smooth homotopy $h\colon[0,1]⨯[0,1]→U$ that contracts $gp$ to a point.

Take the supremum $S$ of $Q⊂[0,1]$ consisting of those $q∈[0,1]$ such that $h$ restricted to $[0,q]⨯[0,1]$ has a (necessarily unique) smooth lifting along $g$.
We claim that $S∈Q$.
Indeed, consider the smooth path $h(S,-)$, which has a smooth lifting along $g$.
By compactness of $[0,1]$, this lifting extends to a smooth lifting
of $h(t,-)$, where $t$ belongs to a sufficiently small open neighborhood $W$ of $S$.  In particular, for $t<S$ this smooth lifting must coincide with the previously constructed smooth lifting along $g$ of the restriction of $h$ to $[0,S)⨯[0,1]$.
Thus $S∈Q$.
This argument also shows that $Q$ is an open subset of $[0,1]$, so $Q=[0,1]$, which completes the proof.